# document.getElementsByName returning undefined and it cannot find the value

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var object = document.getElementsByName("test");
console.log(object[0]);
</script>
</head>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="Hi"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I need it to log "Hi", though it is failing, It says that index [0] is undefined even though when only console logging the object I can see it perfectly along with the value.

I tried using it without an index and it failed obviously because it is a NodeList, I can't see exactly what is wrong and I tried to fix it a lot. I'm sure that index 0 is there and that there is value though I cannot access it..

Comment: Your code seems working fine, Just move your `<input>` above the `<script>` Demo: ` http://jsfiddle.net/tSN5U/`

Comment: This is a better jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tSN5U/1/   If the script is before the html, it doesn't work.  If the script is after the html, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is returning undefined because you're trying to access a DOM element (the `input`) before it has even been parsed by the browser.

Place your `<script>` *after* the HTML you're trying to access.

```
<body>
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="Hi"/>
    <script>
       var object = document.getElementsByName("test");
       console.log(object[0]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to still place my JS above the input element but wait for it to load and then get the value?

Comment: @ChosenWann: You can use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/window.onload)

Answer (score 6):

It's because your javascript is executing before the DOM completes loading.

If you put your script after the `<input>`, your console will show up an [HTMLInputElement]. Then show up the value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="Hi"/>
<script>
var objectTag = document.getElementsByName("test");
console.log(objectTag[0].value);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to still place my JS above the input element but wait for it to load and then get the value?

Comment: You need to wait before the DOM is fully loaded. You can try with jQuery `$(document).ready` function or setting up a timer with `setTimeout` before running your javascript.

Also, for optimal performance and speed loading, it's recommended that you load your scripts just before `</body>` closing tag

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="Hi"/>

<SCRIPT language=javascript>
   var object = document.getElementsByName("test").value;
   console.log(object);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are getting the Dom elements before it's loading finished

use the script as below

```
 <input type="hidden" name="test" value="Hi"/>
    <script>
       var object = document.getElementsByName("test");
       console.log(object[0]);
    </script>
```

or
  you can use external Javascript file and place your coding in javascript file as below

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   var object = document.getElementsByName("test");
           console.log(object[0]);
  }
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` would match `input`, not the name attribute

Comment: @DarrenKopp sorry friend. slight confusion. now i understand my mistake